# ServerAlias does not work

Tags: apache, vhosts

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    www.example.com      # Works
  ServerAlias   new.example.com      # Works
  ServerAlias   example.com          # Does not work - shows apache default "It works"
  DocumentRoot  /usr/share/drupal7   # /tmp shows the same behavior
</VirtualHost>
```

Same ip for all domains ( ping new.example.com = ping www.example.com = ping example.com)

EDIT:

ANY top domain behave like this... www.test.com works - test.com does not...

Comment: Some more information would be helpful

Comment: Are you 100% sure you don't have another `example.com` entry in some other previous directive, such as the main site?

Comment: Don't edit and put RESOLVED. Add an answer and accept your answer. That is the appropriate convention

Comment: Furthermore, your statement about IP resolution contradicts the information in the question.

Comment: ping server and apache server were different

Answer (score 0):

Just write it on one line:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    www.example.com 
    ServerAlias   new.example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot  /usr/share/drupal7
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still no effect. xxx.com - does not work no matter where it is placed (ServerName or ServerAlias)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to already use `example.com` for the main site, i.e., you have this:

```
ServerName example.com
```

outside `<VirtualHost>` containers. When there're several matches, Apache will simply retrieve the first one.